# How can I speed up this SQL view?

Tags: sql-server

I'm a beginner at this so hope you can help.  I'm working in SQL server 2008R2 and have a view that is comprised from four tables all joined together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad.award_id,
                bl.funding_id,
                bl.budget_line,
                dd4.monthnumberofyear AS month,
                dd4.yearcalendar      AS year,
                CASE
                  WHEN frb.full_value IS NULL THEN '0'
                  ELSE frb.full_value
                END                   AS Expenditure_value,
                bl.budget_id,
                frb.accode,
                'Actual'              AS Type
FROM   dw.dbo.dimdate5 AS dd4
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.award_data AS ad
                    ON dd4.fulldate BETWEEN ad.usethisstartdate AND
                                            ad.usethisenddate
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.budget_line AS bl
                    ON bl.award_id = ad.award_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dw.dbo.fctresearchbalances AS frb
                    ON frb.el3 = bl.award_id
                       AND frb.element4groupidnew = bl.budget_line
                       AND dd4.yearfiscal = frb.yr
                       AND dd4.monthnumberfiscal = frb.period
```

The view has 9 columns and 1.5 million rows and growing.  A select * from this view was taking 20 minutes for all the rows.  I added indexes on the fields in the tables that are joined on and that improved it to 10 minutes.  My question is what else could I do to get the select to run faster?

Many thanks, Violet.

Comment: Have you used `Include Actual Execution Plan` when running in SSMS to see where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Did you try using [SQL Profiler??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the case statement.

If you have 1.5 million rows, if you're interesting in the aggregation of those rows rather than the whole set, you might want to sum the rows in fctResearchBalances first and then do the joins.

(It's a bit difficult to determine what else you might benefit from, without seeing the access plan.)

Comment: CASE in select means a bit more CPU used, completely insignificant in this case

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use stored procedure to have buffer cache.
2- you can use indexed view , this means creating index on schemabound views.
3- you can use query hints in join to order the query optimizer to use special kind of join.
4- you can use table partitioning .

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT --#1 - potential bottleneck 
                    ad.award_id
                ,   bl.funding_id
                ,   bl.budget_line
                ,   [month] = dd4.monthnumberofyear 
                ,   [year] = dd4.yearcalendar 
                ,   Expenditure_value = ISNULL(frb.full_value, '0')
                ,   bl.budget_id
                ,   frb.accode
                ,   [type] = 'Actual' 
    FROM dbo.dimdate5 dd4
    LEFT JOIN dbo.award_data ad ON dd4.fulldate BETWEEN ad.usethisstartdate AND ad.usethisenddate
    LEFT JOIN dbo.budget_line bl ON bl.award_id = ad.award_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.fctresearchbalances frb ON frb.el3 = bl.award_id --#2 - join by multiple columns
        AND frb.element4groupidnew = bl.budget_line 
        AND dd4.yearfiscal = frb.yr 
        AND dd4.monthnumberfiscal = frb.period
```

Comment: Can you provide `DDL` of your tables or your execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The CASE statement can be replace by

```
COALESCE(frb.full_value,'0') AS Expenditure_value
```

Without more info it's not possible to tell exactly what is wrong but just to give you some pointers.
When you have so many LEFT JOINS the order of the joins can make a difference.
Do you have standard indexes or covering indexes with included columns?
If you don't have covering indexes, then primary keys matter in the joins. Including all the primary key columns in the join condition will speed up the query.

Then look at your data - do you need all those LEFT JOINS base on the foreign keys between those tables? Depending on your keys a LEFT JOIN may be equivalent to an INNER JOIN.
And with all those LEFT JOINS is having a DISTINCT really useful?

How much RAM do you have? If you have 8GB+ then 1.5m rows is nothing for SQL Server. You need to optimise those joins.